# How append the fields data from backend into JSON file in Typo3

Tags: json, typo3, backend, tx-news, custom-backend

How can I write into existing JSON-file the data from backend-Formular in Typo3 directly?
And how can I later delete some data from JSON, when I delete them from the backend in Typo3?
All JSON enterings have a time stamp.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

as JSON, is not a linear file Format but rather a Serialized object. its not possible to append data to it.

what you have to to is:

1) read the json file 
2) use `json_decode()` to get an stdObject or array
3) manipulate that data Object/array the way you want.
4) use `json_encode()` to convert it back to a string..
5) write it back to a file.

```
// Load The Data
$pathToYourFile = 'paht/somefile.json';
$dataString = file_get_contents($pathToYourFile);
$jsonDataArray = json_decode($dataString, true); // fetch Data as ArrayM
///Maniuplate the data like you want

$jsonDataArray['someValue'] = 'updated Value';

// write it back

$dataString = json_encode($jsonDataArray);
file_put_contents($dataString);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I would try this out. Another question I have. Is it possible to delete some data from existing JSON-file, when they would be deleted from the backend-form in Typo3? E.g. is it possible to find and compare needed data via timestamp to delete?